# Error: Cannot find the Template Property 'Foreground' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid'

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

I'm trying to add the Property 'Foreground' in the ControlTemplate Trigger of Tab Control :

```
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                                        <Setter  Property="Foreground" TargetName="Panel" Value="White"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
```

Unfortunately , I get this error :

> Error Cannot find the Template Property 'Foreground' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid'.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Grid doesn't have a Foreground property.

Comment: Thank you but I fixed the error and I have posted the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by adding :

```
 <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Panel" Value="White"></Setter>
```

So the complete code will be :

```
                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
 <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Panel" Value="White"/>

                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
```